# How to connect to "winscp only" server from linux

Tags: unix, ssh, ftp, scp, winscp

I recieved "winscp" access to server of my customer, to check some files. I tried to connect via ssh, however, only response I have got from server was:

WinSCP: this is end-of-file:0

I tried using midnight commander shell link, ftp, sftp. What could I do, to connect to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) seems to only support the [secure copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy), [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) and [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) protocols. Moreover, the result of your [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_shell) connection indicates that shell access to that server is disabled.

In order of likelihood:

1. Try using proper clients (e.g. [`sftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp), [`lftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp), [`ftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp)), instead of Midnight Commander - from my experience, `mc` is not nearly as stable, useful or compatible as a proper client for remote services.
2. You do not mention having tried [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp). You should try that, although I would find it weird if any server had only `scp` enabled, since `scp` does not allow browsing the remote files - just copying.
3. WinSCP seems to [work well](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1285) with recent versions of [WINE](http://winehq.com/), which is available for most Linux distributions...
4. If all else fails, you could try WinSCP from a Windows virtual machine or even from a real Windows system...

Comment: Thank you. I tried sftp from command line and it worked. All high level tools I used requested access to root directory (/) of server and were not allowed to. Is there any standard way, how to explicitly specify, that I want to start in the home directory?

Comment: With WinSCP you specify the initial remote directory on Directories tab of Login dialog: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_directories